# Renaming multiple columns in r using a pattern matching all and only letters and punctuation and keeping all digits

Tags: r, regex, dplyr, gsub, stringr

I have imported a data frame with huge variations the names of columns, random spaces and punctuation signs that I want to homogenize to get a uniform structure in the shape of "YYYY_varname_AGE" with YYYY and AGE as digits. Each string begins with four digits and ends with 2 digits.

For now, instead of "var_name" I have a huge variety of different letter and punctuation strings that I want to get rid of. There are no clear patterns in the non-digits that I can use to replace with a pattern. I want to select everything between the four first digits and the two last digits and replace it with "varname".

I have tried to make a reproducible example below but R seems to fix/clean it automatically:

```
`1556 VARIAbLE name 23`<- c(1,2,3)
`1557 VAr;NAM: 23` <- c(2,3,4)
`1556 VARNA-Na,M 21-27` <- c(4,5,6)

df <- data.frame(`1556 VARIAbLE name 23`,
                 `1557 VAr;NAM: 23`,
                 `1556 VARNA-Na,M 21-27`)
```

I don't know regex very well. I have tried to match based on the following patterns:
`(^\\d{4}).(\\d{2}$)` and `(^\\d{4})\\D` but they don't work.

```
df %>% 
  rename_with(~gsub("(^\\d{4}).(\\d{2}$)", "(^\\d{4})_varname_(\\d{2}$)", .x))

df %>% 
  rename_with(~gsub("^\\d{4}\\D", "^\\d{4}_varname_", .x))
```

I have also done it manually by matching each string structure and getting rid of all spaces/punctuation/lower case signs but there are a lot of columns in the original dataset and I would prefet to simply match everything between the year and age digits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get your columns names with `names` and to replace everything between the four first digits and the two last digits have to change your regex in the way that you match the digits but not capture them to replace. Something like this:

```
df <- data.frame("1556 VARIAbLE name 23" = c(1),"1557 VAr;NAM: 23" = c(2),
             "1556 VARNA-Na,M 21-27" = c(3))

names(df) <- gsub("(?<=^\\d{4})(.*)(?=\\d{2}$)", "_varname_", names(df), perl=T)
```

**Regex explanation:**

With look behind positive `(?<=)` you will look for four digits to be present behind your capturing group `(.*)` and with look ahead positive `(?=)` fix the condition that two digits follows your capturing group.